# How to update nested object in redux or redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

on edit action call, i want to set data in selectedEmp obj but keep getting immer error

```
const initialState = {
  currentUser: 'user2',
  users: [
    { 
      id: 'user1', email: 'preyash@gmail.com', name: 'preyash', password: 'preyash@gmail.com', 
      loggedIn: false, selectedEmp: {},
      emps: [
        { id: 1, empName: 'preyash', salary: '50000', gender: 'male' },
        { id: 2, empName: 'chintan', salary: '40000', gender: 'male' },
      ],
    },
    { 
      id: 'user2', email: 'uiux5@varaluae.com', name: 'uiux5', password: 'uiux5@varaluae.com', 
      loggedIn: true, selectedEmp: {},
      emps: [
        { id: 1, empName: 'twisha', salary: '50000', gender: 'female' },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

edit: (state, action) => {
      let obj = state.users.find(i=>i.id == state.currentUser)
      let index = state.users.findIndex(i=>i.id == state.currentUser)
      let empObj = obj.emps.find((i) => i.id == action.payload);
      state.users.splice(index, 1, { ...obj, selectedEmp: empObj })
      let newUsers = current(state.users)
      return { 
        ...state, 
        users: newUsers
      };
    },
```

This is the output i want, Pls HELP

```
{ 
      id: 'user2', email: 'uiux5@varaluae.com', name: 'uiux5', password: 'uiux5@varaluae.com', 
      loggedIn: true, selectedEmp: { id: 1, empName: 'twisha', salary: '50000', gender: 'female' },
      emps: [
        { id: 1, empName: 'twisha', salary: '50000', gender: 'female' },
      ],
    }
```

Here is the project url:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-int6dt?file=src/reducers/userSlice.js

Answer (score 1):

In a `createSlice` reducer you can just use modifying logic, so if you want to remove an element from `state.users`, you just do

```js
let index = state.users.findIndex(i=>i.id == state.currentUser)
state.users.splice(index, 1)
```

no additional code.

If you then want to set `state.currentUser` to `undefined`, you just do

```js
state.currentUser = undefined
```

You do not need to `return` anything from the reducer.

I'd recommend you give [writing reducers with `immer`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) a read.